# How to add canonical tags in wordpress category/archive pages?

Tags: wordpress, seo, canonical-link

I think wordpress auto generate `canonical` tags for the single post pages (I am using wp 3.3.2 ). But it is not in category or archive pages. How should I add canonical tags to those pages?

I have tried following code in `header.php` file

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$uri = "http://www.mydomain.com" . $path;
print('<link rel="canonical" href="' . $uri . '"/>');
```

But this give just the request URL not the master/parent  URL of the page.
I just want to get `canonical` tags from the wordpress same as single post page did. Not like this kind of custom code. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your header

```
if(is_category()) {
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $category_id = $categories[0]->term_id;
    echo '<link rel="canonical" href="' .  get_category_link($category_id) . '" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any SEO plugins?

http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/